# What is garena.com in relation to League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

I saw a link to this URL

http://lol.garena.com/

The title says League of Legends Singapore, but the Riot LoL site doesn't appear to have any links? Is it a third party implementation of LoL or perhaps an instance of LoL that was bought/rented from Riot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Garena does appear to be an official partner, according to [this forum thread](http://www.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=519379).

> I have good news for those among you who are located in Singapore and Malaysia. We are pleased to announce that League of Legends has officially entered Open Beta in these regions. In conjunction **with our partner**, Garena, we are offering free account transfers to those summoners who wish to play in their home region.

Comment: Wait... do you mean... Singapore is... _supported?_ Surely that can't be the case!

Answer (score 1):

Garena publishes LoL for the Singapore and Malaysia market.

See: http://vr-zone.com/articles/garena-officially-launches-league-of-legends-on-friday-the-13th/12199.html